# WAR file servlet access: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, servlets, websphere

After much reading of examples online I created a WAR file with a web.xml containing:

```
<servlet> <description>This is a servlet host for the
transformer</description> <display-name>Transformer</display-name>
<servlet-name>transformer</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.pepsi.transformer.TransformerServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> </servlet>
```

And then in my .java file I have:

```
package com.pepsi.transformer;
...
public class TransformerServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
```

Then I built my ant script to stuff the TransformerServlet.class file into the WEB-INF/classes part of the WAR file. I have inspected it afterwords and found the .class file was there exactly as intended.

So ... then why do I see this error when I try to hit the doGet from the browser?

> 00000099 annotation W
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses
>   SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation
>   scanning. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.pepsi.transformer.TransformerServlet at
>   jav.lang.ClassforNameImpl(Native Method) ...

Did I overspecify the package? Should the classes folder contain un-compiled .java files? Does it need an init method? Does something else on the server need to know about this class file?

Comment: When you say you put TransformerServlet.class into the WEB-INF/classes did you put it directly in that folder? i.e. is it WEB-INF/classes/TransformerServlet.class or is it WEB-INF/classes/com/pepsi/transformer/TransformerServlet.class

Comment: I'd really suggest you to use any Java EE IDE, like Eclipse. It will create all that for you when you will create simple dynamic web project. Also unless required, it is much easier to use `@WebServlet` annotation instead of defining servlet in `web.xml`. Go to the https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-eclipse/ and follow instructions to download and configure Eclipse with WebSphere Liberty.

Comment: @Alasdair: Looks like they were going into WEB-INF and not WEB-INF/classes. Should they go into separate directories for each token in the fully qualified package name?

Comment: Yes. Each token in the package name has to map to a directory name in a path.

Comment: With Ant, you want to use the `<war>` task and its `<classes>` element to point at the root of the package hierarchy directory.